# Groups from LDAP: "getent" reports membership correctly but missing in output of "id"

Tags: group, ldap, getent

I have a Debian 10 machine which uses PAM LDAP for authentication. In LDAP I have two users `alice` and `bob` which are both members of group `mygroup`. Everything has worked fine (so the configuration shouldn't be too far off) until I recently discovered some weirdness with my groups (not sure what happened):

- `ldapsearch` reports user `alice` as a member of group `mygroup` (as it should).
- `getent group` shows user `alice` as a member of group `mygroup` (as it should).

  ```
  root@tux:~# getent group | grep mygroup
  mygroup:*:1210:alice,bob
  ```
- `id` does *not* report `alice` to be a member of group `mygroup`:

  ```
  root@tux:~# id alice
  uid=1200(alice) gid=1200(alice) groups=1200(alice)
  ```
- Surprisingly enough user `bob` is reported to be a member of `mygroup`:

  ```
  root@tux:~# id bob
  uid=1201(bob) gid=1201(bob) groups=1210(mygroup),1201(bob)
  ```

So far I thought that both `getent` and `id` are getting their information from the Name Service Switch library (NSS). I'm confused and hoping for some hints how to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

With some implementations of LDAP it's necessary not only to define the members of a group but also to define the groups of which a user is a member. (One isn't implied by the other - both relationships have to be stated explicitly.)

Look at the LDAP records for *alice* and *bob*, do they show group memberships? If so, check that *alice* and *bob* are indeed both members of mygroup.

Similarly, look at *mygroup*, and confirm that *alice* and *bob* are both members of it.